# Combining geom_jitter and geom_count and after_stat(n) to get jittered plots of counts by treatment

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, bubble-chart

This has been killing me, it should be so simple. I would like to make a scatterplot in which both axes are count data, so each [x,y] location of two integer values has a substantial amount of overlapping points. For each of these x,y points I would like to show (and specify) 2 treatments by colour, 8 trials by alpha (or shape), and *crucially*, the count of points at that locus (separated by treatment/trial) by size. It seems that geom_jitter and geom_count allow some elements of each but I can't combine them.

The data is zero-heavy, so I'm expecting 16 large overlapping circles at 0,0, which it would be nice to jitter as in a bubble plot. I'm also happy to use other approaches outside ggplot2 if these things can't be combined within it. Many thanks in advance!